# How to know what are the limits for Shield history tracking in salesforce

Tags: history-tracking, field-history

We recently have Shield enabled in our organsiation, we want to check if number of fields allowed for history tracking are same in sandboxes or differnt,

IS ther any simple way where we can check what are the limits between our orgs
Anything like

```
SELECT ParentId, FieldHistoryType, Field, Id, NewValue, OldValue FROM FieldHistoryArchive
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can track upto 60 fields per object and it should be same for all sandboxes.

Please check below info

https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/07/introducing-salesforce-shield.html

Field Audit Trail gives customers a time machine so they can go back in time and see the state and value of their data on any date, at any time. It expands what is currently available with Field History Retention, giving customers up to 10 years of audit trail data for up to **60 fields per object**.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=field_audit_trail.htm&language=en_US%E2%80%8B

The HistoryRetentionPolicy is automatically set on the above objects, once Field Audit Trail is enabled. By default, **data is archived after 18 months in a production organization, after one month in a sandbox organization**, and all archived data is stored for 10 years.

http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/21/en-us/sfdc/pdf/field_history_retention.pdf